# Embedding HTML5 Video Into Static Front Page In WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a splash type page using the static front page method in WordPress, and I am trying to get a four second video to play when the page is loaded.  I know how to get the video to autoplay that is not the issue.  The issue is the vid isn't displaying.

I was able to create the static front page by creating a front-page.php template file. The code I placed in this file is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Iron Triangle Films Splash Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.">
    <style>
    .mainContent{
     margin-left: 275px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>

 <div style="border:solid 1px black;"class="mainContent">

 <video id="my_video" height="500" width="700" autoplay>

 <source src=itf.mp4 type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>

 <source src=itf.ogv type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
 </video>

 </div><!--End Main Content div-->

</body>
</html>
```

The page loads as the front page, but the vid does not display.  Here's a [link to the site](http://www.irontrianglefilms.com).

Comment: http://irontrianglefilms.com/itf.mp4 HTTP 404

Comment: Thanks for responding. Why can't it find it? The file 'itf.mp4' is in the same directory as the front-page.php file. It doesn't even need to go into another folder such as a 'video' folder. It should be able to find it. What is missing? I'd appreciate it. Thanks, CM –

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your video file `itf.mp4` doesn't exist, so the browser can't play it.

The browser is looking here: http://irontrianglefilms.com/itf.mp4

Which, as you can see, 404s (in a very spammy HostGator way :().

It's quite likely that you've placed the video file in your theme directory, which isn't the same directory as far as the browser is concerned.  You can either place the file in your web root (bad idea), or properly link to the file:

```
<source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/itf.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Why can't it find it?  The file 'itf.mp4' is in the same directory as the front-page.php file.  It doesn't even need to go into another folder such as a 'video' folder.  It should be able to find it.  What is missing? I'd appreciate it.  Thanks, CM

Comment: Mike I've got it working in Firefox, but it's not working in Chrome, Safari or IE. Any ideas?

www.irontrianglefilms.com

Comment: Nothing has changed.  Your file still 404s.

Comment: It's now working across all browsers after you implemented my code from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make unmuted & loop video on home page on Wordpress. And final out put came on custome code on wizard.It is easy and simple now just copy - past the code and change your video link.

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" id="myVideo"><source src="https://trianglefilms.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/triangle-films-Main.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```